# FPDF - How to remove a vertical line in the generated file

Tags: pdf, export, tcpdf, fpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF file from an html content using FPDF

```
            $this->pdf->AddPage();          
            $html = "Hello World";
            $footer = "Footer";
            $this->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
            $this->pdf->SetXY(1,255);
            $this->pdf->MultiCell(208, 20, $footer, 0, "C", false, 0, '','',true,0,true,true,0,'B',false);
```

The generated file contains a vertical line on the top of the page (above Hello World). After few tests I found out that it's added by AddPage(), I get that it's sort of a seperator of pages but I don't want to keep it and didn't find how to remove it.

Also, it doesn't seem like a common issue so I don't know if I'm missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using TCPDF instead of FPDF. So just disable the automated page header via the [setPrintHeader()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a9240c96d0ce715acb3ebe8e8362202f7) method.

Comment: THANK YOU ! I used setPrintHeader(false); and it worked like magic. Appreciated your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Open the api's code, go to the AddPage() function and modify it...remove the line that is being added.

Comment: Thanks, I went to AddPage() and specifically to Header() in TCPDF class, where I changed the style given to that line, but lastly I ended up using the `setPrintHeader(false);` proposed by Setasign which is the more correct way to solve it.

Comment: @JennaSMITH good :) .please vote up and marked the question as answered ..thanks